# Get inline email attachments with PHP in a formatted email send from an IOS device

Tags: php, ios, email, imap, attachment

I'm using [PHP-imap](http://code.google.com/p/php-imap/) to read emails and there attachments from a IMAP Account. The emails are send from an iPhone or iPad. It works fine when they write an email and paste in an image they took.

Here's a snippet how I get the attachments:

```
require_once("plugins/MailLib/MailLib.php");

$mailbox = new MailLib();
$mailbox->connect($username, $password, $server, $port, $path, false);

$mails = array();
$mailIds = $mailbox->getMails("UNSEEN");

if($mailIds != null && count($mailIds) > 0) {
    foreach($mailIds as $mailId) {
        $mail = $mailbox->getMail($mailId);
        if($mail['attachments']) {
            foreach($mail['attachments'] as $attachment) {
                $file = $mailbox->getAttachment($attachment, $mailId);
                $destFile = "path/to/folder/".time().".jpg";
                $fh = fopen($destFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
                fwrite($fh, $file);
                fclose($fh);
            }
        }
 }
```

It all crashes as soon as they start formatting the content with the default options like bold, italic or underline. Because then I get the following email content:

```
<div>
    <em>Test</em> with <strong>formatting</strong>
    <br>
    <br>
    <img id="7CB777EB-3124-4AEA-8894-6F743EA78F79" src="cid:7CB777EB-3124-4AEA-8894-6F743EA78F79" alt="image.jpeg">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>Send from my iPhone</div>
</div>
```

Is there any kind of php library out there to get those attachments as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem. Someone wrote a [small class to extract inline attachments](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-email-extract-inline-image-attachments/).

With this class it is possible to write the attachment content direct to a file, like the following:

```
foreach($emailMessage->attachments as $attachment) {
    file_put_contents(time().".extension", $attachment['data']);
}
```